# Subtype check error for lambda

Tags: java, checker-framework

I am trying to implement a simple [subtyping check](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#subtyping-checker) for the checker-framework.
It does basically work, but I get an error related to lambda-usage that I don't understand.

I've created a simple test-project on github: [checkerfw-test](https://github.com/tmtron/checkerfw-test) so that anyone can easily reproduce the issue.

The typesystem that I use is much like the `RegEx` example in the [docs](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#regex-checker)/[src](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/tree/master/checker/src/org/checkerframework/checker/regex/qual).
Here's a link to [my types](https://github.com/tmtron/checkerfw-test/tree/testFromCallable2_fails/mSubtypes/src/main/java/com/tmtron/checkerfw):

- `IdDomainObject` is the top type
- `IdUser`, `IdCustomer` are the custom types that should not be assignable to each other
- `IdBottom` is the bottom type

The compilation of my **[testFromCallable2()](https://github.com/tmtron/checkerfw-test/blob/testFromCallable2_fails/src/main/java/com/tmtron/checkerfw/Subtyping.java#L67)** function:

```
static class GenericHolder<T> {
    public T field;
}

public static <T> GenericHolder<T> fromCallable(final Callable<? extends T> callable) {
    GenericHolder<T> result = new GenericHolder<T>();
    try {
        result.field = callable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public void testFromCallable2() {
    GenericHolder<@IdCustomer Long> tmp2 = fromCallable(() -> {
                final @IdCustomer Long customerId = toCustomerId(1);
                return customerId;
            }
    );
}
```

**fails** with this error-message:

```
      GenericHolder<@IdCustomer Long> tmp2 = fromCallable(() -> {

   required: @IdDomainObject GenericHolder<@IdCustomer Long>
```

I don't think this should fail, because the lambda returns exactly the specified type.

The test-source also contains a function [testFromCallable1](https://github.com/tmtron/checkerfw-test/blob/testFromCallable2_fails/src/main/java/com/tmtron/checkerfw/Subtyping.java#L52), which does the same, just without a lambda and this code works:

```
public void testFromCallable1() {
    GenericHolder<@IdCustomer Long> tmp = fromCallable(new Callable<@IdCustomer Long>() {
        @Override
        public @IdCustomer Long call() throws Exception {
            final @IdCustomer Long customerId = toCustomerId(1);
            return customerId;
        }
    });
}
```

What am I missing?

Note:
I am just beginning to use the subtype-checker, so I think I did not understand all the docs about subtyping yet: e.g. maybe I have just set some wrong values for some of the annotations on my type-definitions (e.g. `@ImplicitFor`, `@DefaultFor`, ...)

I am using checker-framework version `2.2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Checker Framework doesn't yet fully implement Java 8 type inference.  See [Issue #979](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues/979).  You can work around this limitation by explicitly specifying the type argument to `fromCallable`.

```
GenericHolder<@IdCustomer Long> tmp2 = this.<@IdCustomer Long>fromCallable(() -> {
           final @IdCustomer Long customerId = toCustomerId(1);
            return customerId;
        }
);
```

`testFromCallable1` doesn't issue the error because it doesn't use Java 8 type inference.